# Objective C - XMLReader miscounting Array

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, xmlreader

Need help in Objective C count JSON objects.

I'm using github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader/ to read my XML.

If my JSON returns more than 1 object my code counts the objects perfectly.
But if my JSON returns only ONE object it miscounts.

Here is my JSON with 2 objects:

```
QuestionTotal = {
Question = ({
    Description = {
        text = "bla bla";
    };
    id = {
        text = "123";
    };
    ord = {
        text = 1;
    };
}, {
    Description = {
        text = "blu blu";
    };
    id = {
        text = "456";
    };
    ord = {
        text = 2;
    };
});
```

};

My objective c code:

```
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary;

NSMutableArray *questions = [[[[[[[self.xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"Envelope"] objectForKey:@"Body"] objectForKey:@"GetInterviewResponse"] objectForKey:@"GetInterviewResult"] objectForKey:@"Obj"] objectForKey:@"QuestionsTotal"] objectForKey:@"Question"];
```

NSLog(@"Total questions: %lu", (unsigned long)[questions count]);

The code above return Log: Total questions: 2

If JSON is:

```
QuestionTotal = {
Question = {
    Description = {
        text = "bla bla";
    };
    id = {
        text = "123";
    };
    ord = {
        text = 1;
    };
};
```

};

The code returns Log: Total questions: 3
Which is wrong.

Comment: Where is Envelope, Body, GetInterviewResponse, etc in your json?

Comment: Hi, my code returns all those nodes. I did not inserted them in the post for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Do you really believe that _Objective-C_ is _miscounting_???

Comment: Nope. I just found that XMLReader does not insert parenthesis when only one value is returned. The first JSON ends with parenthesis. The second doesn't. Could be this?

https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader/issues/14

Comment: We need to see the full json document to eliminate it's contents as the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that I needed to insert this code for XMLReader to work:

```
if (![list isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    // if 'list' isn't an array, we create a new array containing our object
    list = [NSArray arrayWithObject:list];
}
```

And when the array has only one object, everything works fine.

Thanks everyone.